# Managing multiple mqtt devices from one place

Tags: mqtt

I have a raspberry pi device with an mqtt. It works in the form of sending - receiving data from the cloud broker.

I want to reproduce. I do not know how to do it.
I will have a raspberry pi device with multiple Mqtts, they will send and receive data from one place. Is it right to do this?

Or a mqtt - should it be a broker for everyone, but what if my mqtt is 1000-10000?

Actually: How can I do this to manage multiple mqtt devices from one place?

[image]

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are asking here. What is "an mqtt"? Do you really mean a MQTT client? If so then we really don't have enough information to answer properly (e.g. message rate, size of message, subscriber to publisher ratio) but a modern MQTT broker can handle 100's of thousands (or more) of clients under the right circumstances

Comment: I am new to this. Devices must have Client.
As far as I understand, I can send/receive N number of client data with 1 broker?

In what I do, I process the sensor data that comes to me and make it act accordingly. All that will work in this logic

Comment: Looks like you need a tutorial. Google "MQTT Tutorial" or look at our lab https://mqttlab.iotsim.io

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

MQTT broker by its nature is to "broke" messages from one client to another.
An MQTT broker (maybe cluster) is a perfect choice. e.g. each client can subscribe to a topic with their self-assigned client ID (an MQTT client must have an ID, self-assigned or created by broker) such as `commands/client-0001/#` to receive all commands for itself. Clients may also subscribe to `commands/broadcast` to receive messages intended for all.
If you are to have centralized management, a management client may publish commands to one specific client, or broadcast to all.
Likewise, the same topic as the above example can be used for clients to communicate with each other.
In case you may want to know more brokers: https://docs.emqx.io/en/broker/v4.3/